# How to change Cursor Icon upon button click on React

Tags: css, reactjs, button, pseudo-element, mouse-cursor

How do I change my cursor to be an icon when I click a button and then place that icon down on the second click, and become a regular cursor again? I'm working in React. All I have is that when I button is clicked, the global boolean clicked is turned to true.

Comment: Can you please provide some code ?

Comment: [check this](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/) this will show you how to add custom custom cursor with css. And in react you need to add class onClick event and remove that with reclick. You can use state to add remove class

Comment: See this and look at hover example https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp also I see css cursor property  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Answer (score 8):

Is this useful for what you need?

```
const [cursor, setCursor] = useState('crosshair');


  const changeCursor = () => {
    setCursor(prevState => {
      if(prevState === 'crosshair'){
        return 'pointer';
      }
      return 'crosshair';
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ cursor: cursor }}>

      <h2>Click to change mouse cursor</h2>
      <input  type="button" value="Change cursor" 
      onClick={changeCursor}
      style={{ cursor: cursor }}

      />
    </div>
  );
```

[image: Edit React - Change cursor example]

Comment: This works for me! How would I add a custom cursor component? I have a png named altCursor.png  in my styles folder, but this file is outside my syles folder.

Comment: @user12677345 I am not sure, in this [page](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/) they use `url()` to define custom cursors